# Running executable from Crontab

Tags: linux, email, centos, cron

I have a file called `Exim_queue_size` in the root directory. It contains one line:

```
exim -bpc | mail -s'Exim_queue_size' bert@example.com
```

It has had its permissions set with chmod +x , and is thus executable.

If I run `./Exim_queue_size`, it works perfectly and mails the queue size count.

If I load to run in the crontab, with the line

```
0 3,6,9,12,15,18,21,0 * * * /root/Exim_queue_size
```

I receive a correctly titled e-mail with no count attached.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Please provide the misbehaving entry exactly as stated in your crontab. In addition, please provide any configuration/environment lines, if present, from your crontab. I suspect environment difference.

Comment: @Jarmund My cron entry is and i see no environment/config line in the crontab file.
`code`

0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * * /root/Exim_queue_size

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but exim might be in a location that is not in your path by default. And if exim is not found a blank message is what your script will produce.

When you login, you have a variety of files like .bashrc that add directories to your path. But these config files are not all sourced when cron runs. Try this on the command line...

```
$ which exim
/usr/local/somepath/exim
```

Then use the resulting full path in your script...

```
/usr/local/somepath/exim -bpc | mail -s'Exim_queue_size' bert@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, however the crontab calls the executable in the root, and the executable works perfectly when run as ./Exim_queue_size from its location in the root directory. So still looking. FWIW exim is at /usr/bin/exim :-)

Comment: Well it's not at all inconceivable that it would run perfectly from a login shell and then fail from cron. But yeah, it's unlikely that cron does not have /usr/bin in its path.  Sure, sorry that didn't help.

Comment: You might be able to see what is going on by redirecting stderr and stdout to a temp file from cron...  "exim -bpc >>/tmp/crontest 2>&1"     I suspect it has to do be something going wrong with that part of the command since you are getting an email. After that runs you can cat /tmp/crontest and see if there is anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I edited executable Exim_queue_size to read

/usr/bin/exim -bpc | mail -s'Exim_queue_size' bert@example.com

as suggested by Bill Heller, and on the cron run at 3am, the correct mail was received. Problem solved. Thank you.